# Mysql - Populate data in one column based on join with three different fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, left-join, inner-join

We are maintaining Address of say House, school, office in one address table.I want to get 'state' column in a new table based on the below condition.

populate state column, if House id matches with house id in Address table , else if school id matches else if office id matches.

Address Table:

```
Address Id  State City
SC001       Iowa  Cedar
HO001       Iowa  Cedar
HO002       Ohio  Columbus
OF002       Ohio  Columbus
```

New Table

```
School Office   House   State
SC001    OF001    HO001   Iowa
SC002    OF002    HO002   Ohio
```

Thanks

Comment: "New Table" is actually a table ? or you want the expected output from "Address Table" to be like "New Table"

Comment: Where does `'SC002'` come from?  It is not in the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `lef join` the `new_table` three times, and use `coalesce()` for prioritization:

```
update address_table a
left join new_table n1 on n1.house_id  = a.addres_id
left join new_table n2 on n2.school_id = a.addres_id
left join new_table n2 on n3.office_id = a.addres_id
set a.state = coalesce(n1.state, n2.state, n3.state)
where coalesce(n1.house_id, n2.school_id, n3.office_id) is not null
```

The `where` clause ensures that at least one of the joins succeded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query out:

```
SELECT NewTable.State FROM NewTable WHERE 
NewTable.School IN (SELECT AddressTable.AdressId FROM AddressTable) 
OR NewTable.Office IN (SELECT AddressTable.AdressId FROM AddressTable) 
OR NewTable.House IN (SELECT AddressTable.AdressId FROM AddressTable);
```